# Почему не собирает данные на след странице?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Не могу понять, почему не собирает данные на след. странице (https://b2b.placek.cz/). Вроде перехожу, на нее, жду подгрузки, данные есть, но почему то проскакивает на следующую и в итоге выходит из цикла в другу категорию. И да, при обновлении страницы подгружается первая страница.

```
 def parse():
        for category in categorys:
            html = category[1]['href']
            FILE = category[0]['category_name']
            driver.get(html)
            driver.implicitly_wait(3)
            # подгружаем кукисы
            for cookie in pickle.load(open(f"{login}_cookies", "rb")):
                driver.add_cookie(cookie)
            driver.implicitly_wait(2)
            # обновим страничку чтоб авторизоваться
            driver.refresh()
            driver.implicitly_wait(2)
            products_all = []
            print(f"Идет парсинг категории {FILE}...")
            try:
                # for page_count in range(160):
                #     products_all.extend(get_content(html))
                #     print(f".....")
                while True:
                    try:
                        products_all.extend(get_content(html))
                        print(f".....")
                        # WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_element_located(
                        #     (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")))
                        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, (
                            '/html/body/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')).click()
                        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
                        #driver.refresh()
                        #driver.implicitly_wait(2)

                    except Exception:
                        break
            except Exception:
                try:
                    save_file(products_all, FILE)
                except PermissionError:
                    print(f"Закройте {FILE}, не могу в него сохранять!")
                continue

        print(f"Сбор данных завершен успешно.")
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть url страницы которую парсить пытатесь дали.

Comment: там просто требуется авторизация, незнаю на сколько этот url поможет, но вот он https://b2b.placek.cz/